# Using sequence next val in sql to enter all values from the sequence to row of a table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE SEQUENCE pri_series_new
    START WITH 100000
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 000000
    MAXVALUE 99999999
    cycle
```

i need all the values this sequence generates into a  table's row.

```
INSERT into pri_temp VALUES(pri_series_new.nextval);
```

this inserts only one value at a time i need all the values to be inserted.

the row in the table should contain all the numbers that a sequence object is generating.

Comment: you have defined a sequence as a cycle, so what do you mean by "all the numbers that a sequence object is generating"

Comment: The `INSERT` statement you posted inserts exactly one (1) row into database table `pri_temp`. Are you  looking for a way to insert more than one row?

Comment: yes i need to insert more than one row. 99899999 to be exact

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a sequence, you just need a row-source...

```
insert 
  into pri_temp
select seq     
  from (select level as seq from dual connect by level <= 99999999)
 where seq >= 100000;
```

Comment: can it be a direct relation `insert into table values(column) as select sequence.nextval from table where sequence.nextval <=99999999 --maxvalueofsequence`

Comment: Which part of your problem still remains unsolved? The query I have provided will populate the table with records as per your question. I suspect that you are using sequences in a non-standard way, which leads to side-effects and problems that you are now asking for help with. If you could provide a little more background it will be easier to provide a *good* answer :)

Comment: your answer is absolutely correct. I am not the OP who has asked the above query but I was asking a kind of suggestion from you in the comment prior

Comment: Oops, sorry my misstake! 
You can select from any table as long as it has the required number of rows. But you can't use a sequence in the where-clause.

Comment: ohhkay, i went wrong with the where clause. thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you:

```
DECLARE
    maxvalue number;
BEGIN
    select MAX_VALUE into maxvalue from all_sequences where sequence_name='PRI_SERIES_NEW';
    FOR i IN 1..maxvalue LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT into pri_temp VALUES(PRI_SERIES_NEW.nextval)';
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the following version of SQL.

Note: I have used INCREMENT_BY to handle the situation where INCREMENT_BY of the sequence is other than 1.

```
INSERT INTO PRI_TEMP
    SELECT
        PRI_SERIES_NEW.NEXTVAL
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                ( MAX_VALUE - LAST_NUMBER + INCREMENT_BY ) / INCREMENT_BY AS LOOP_CNT
            FROM
                USER_SEQUENCES
            WHERE
                SEQUENCE_NAME = 'PRI_SERIES_NEW'
        )
    CONNECT BY
        LEVEL <= LOOP_CNT;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0de65b1ced3cec4513ade47511c1a5b7)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this.

```
INSERT into pri_temp
select pri_series_new.nextval
  from dual
 connect by rownum <= (SELECT max_value FROM all_sequences WHERE lower(sequence_name) = 'pri_series_new')
```